# tortoiseGit "show log" function cannot be used anymore

Tags: git, tortoisegit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZGNE.png)

Just like this, I wait a long time, but nothing is shown. DIfferently, my tortoiseSvn's "show log" function works well.

I want to us tortoiseGit's "show log" function. Please help me, thanks.

Comment: There are two sliders that can be used to resize the three areas vertically.

Answer (score 0):

There are two sliders that can be used to resize the three areas vertically.